# Can Django write JSON to an input and use it in a template as well as read it back?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

This uses Django with Python 2.5.  I have a list of dicts that I want to write to a template variable in a view and also be able to recover the list when the form is submitted.  I am only able to do one or the other.

When I use render_to_response with the list of dicts, I can use the value in the template, but the keys are single-quoted so simplejson.loads fails.  If I convert the list of dicts using simplejson.dumps before render_to_response, I can recover the list with loads, but the template sees the variable as a string.

To both use the variable in the template and recover the list later, I need to write to two inputs in the view.  It seems like I'm missing something.

Here is an example.

test.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.utils import simplejson

def test(request):
    test_dict_list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'d1': 4,'e2': 5}]
    test_dict_list_json = simplejson.dumps(test_dict_list)

    str1 = request.GET.get("test_dict_list")
    # u"[{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}, {'e2': 5, 'd1': 4}]"

    try:
        simplejson.loads(str1)
        # fails because keys are single-quoted
    except:
        pass

    str2 = request.GET.get("test_dict_list_json")
    # u'[{"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 2}, {"e2": 5, "d1": 4}]'

    try:
        list1 = simplejson.loads(str2)
    # correct list of dicts since  keys are double quoted
    # [{u'a': 1, u'c': 3, u'b': 2}, {u'd1': 4, u'e2': 5}]
    except:
        pass

    return render_to_response('testview.html',
                               {'test_dict_list': test_dict_list,
                                'test_dict_list_json': test_dict_list_json})
```

testview.html:

```
<h1>Testing</h1>

<form name="test_form" action="{% url test %}" method="get">
    <h3>test_dict_list = {{ test_dict_list }}</h3>
    {% for elt in test_dict_list %}
        <ul>{{ elt }}</ul>
    {% endfor %}

    <h3>test_dict_list_json = {{ test_dict_list_json }}</h3>
    {% for elt in test_dict_list_json %}
        <ul>{{ elt }}</ul>
    {% endfor %}

    <input name="test_submit" type="submit" class="cpa-button" value="Test submit"/>

    {# Invisible input to store persistent values across page loads #}
    <input name="test_dict_list" type="text" style="display:none" value="{{ test_dict_list }}"/>
    <input name="test_dict_list_json" type="text" style="display:none" value="{{ test_dict_list_json }}"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you think you are missing something. JSON is a text interchange format. If you dump a dict to JSON, it is converted to a string, and you can't iterate through its items. If you simply output a dictionary as a string, it will not be valid JSON. Python's dictionary literal format is close to JSON, but not exactly the same.

Comment: I thought I was missing something since this is so tantalizingly close to working.  It would work if 1) django didn't coerce the key quotes to single quotes and instead made them double quotes and 2) used single quotes in the HTML value instead of the double quotes it does use.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a templatetag for converting the dictionary into a JSON string from within the template?  Custom template tags are very powerful and surprisingly easy to write.  More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you sending json to the template in the first place?

You can render from a dictionary in a template using a for loop

```
{% for key,value in my_dictionary.items %}
    <li>{{key}}:{{value}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Furthermore - don't encode to json and store in a webpage just so you can send it back to yourself again -- this is what sessions (or messages) are for. In your views do this:

```
request.session['mydict'] = my_dictionary
```

On the next view, you can simply recover the dictionary with

```
request.session['mydict']
```

I'd suggest checking to make sure `'mydict' in request.session` though and handle failure accordingly, just to be safe.

Comment: If it is in the session, then it is hidden.  If it is explicitly sent back, then the view can be recreated from the URL.

Comment: Why do you want to recreate the view from the url, as opposed to using the same data? As for hidden, what do you mean? You can render the dict to the user if that is what you desire and save both of you the bandwidth of sending it back and forth unnecessarily by keeping the same copy in the session. Maybe I just don't understand what you are using it for.

Comment: As an example, consider buying tickets. In step one (view 1), tickets are reserved and the user confirms them.  In step two (view 2), he purchases them.  In step two, I want to know what the tickets are.  Using the session would work fine and you are right about sending the data unnecessarily.  But I thought there was a potential benefit (maybe just ideological - REST?) to having the data completely specified in the URL.